# Python 3.x: Pandas DataFrame How to overwrite csv files (batch process)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of csv files in a folder. I was batch-processing the csv files. 
But when I read it using my pandas dataframe, it reads the files as the followings.

```
0     -1     4650.0         NaN
1      0        0.0         NaN
2      1        0.0         NaN
3      2        0.0         NaN
4      3        0.0         NaN
5      4        0.0         NaN
6      5        0.0         NaN
```

I have many many csv files in this directory. I want to delete the last columns and overwrite it in the same filename. Any idea? I can't possibly open all the files and store it as variables and delete the column.

Comment: Do the csv files all have the same format? So the same data and the columns in the same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could just **not read** the last column.

If your original file has 3 columns, then `pd.read_csv('filepath', usecols=[0, 1])` should do the trick.

This way, you would be using only columns 0 (first) and 1 (second).

Answer (score 0):

The answer posted by @victor-valente is the better approach to processing those csv files. However, if you still want to remove that Nan column from the files altogether, you can do something like this -

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
csv_files = list(glob.glob("path/to/directory/*.csv"))
for i in csv_files:
    pd.read_csv(i, usecols=[0,1,2]).to_csv(i)
```

This should overwrite the existing files after having removed that 4th empty column.

Something simpler would be to just do a `df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all', inplace=True)` on the df you have built after batch processing your csv files. This would drop any columns that only contain `NaN` values.